# How to take expectation of the Utility Function $\mathbb{E} (\left(y_2k+R_+B_+\right)^{-\gamma})$

Tags: calculus, bayesian, utility, expectation-maximization

How do I take the Expectations of the equation:

$$\mathbb{E} (\left(y_2k+R_+B_+\right)^{-\gamma})$$